# Event for window show or mainloop started in TKinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there an event in `Tkinter` I can bind to which indicates that the *creation of the main window was finished and the window is show* or *if the `mainloop()` started*?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def task():
    print('foobar')

root.after(5000, task)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to `<Visibility>` or `<Map>` events.

```
def task(event):
    ...
root.bind("<Visibility>", task)
```

Another way is to simply run your task with `after_idle`:

```
def task():
    ...
root.after_idle(task)
```

Comment: I tested `<Map>` and `<Visibility>`. They doesn't really do what is in my mind. But `after_idle()` is a nice workaround and will fit my needs.

Comment: Those events should work, though if you call `update` during initialization, that will trigger those events.

Comment: But they are triggered multiple times. I need only one event.

Comment: @buhtz: you are correct. I should have mentioned that. You just need to check the `widget` attribute of the event object to only run your task on the root window.

Comment: This isn't working because the event first occurse for the toplevel window. This makes no sense in my case. I want to know when all widgets are finaly created and finished.

Comment: @Bryan should have mentioned that when you bind an event to the root window, it also gets bound to all that window's children — not very helpful most of the time IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Upon digging, I found this solution:

```
root.wait_visibility()
foo()
root.mainloop()
```

Where foo() is the function you want to run the moment the GUI becomes visible

ref:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2008-April/001392.html